# Bash how to find turn all txt files into myfile.txt

Tags: bash

I have these files.

```
folder1
    file1.txt
    folder11
       fil2.txt


folder2
    file3.txt
    folder22
       filer.txt
```

And I want to transorm all *txt files into the same named file: myfile.txt, i.e,

```
folder1
    myfile.txt
    folder11
       myfile.txt

folder2
    myfile.txt
    folder22
       myfile.txt
```

I have tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} myfile.txt \;
```

But it remove the txt files...

Comment: What if a directory has more than one `.txt` file?

Comment: @anubhava well, it will not happen in my case

Comment: In that case how can you have all `.txt` files renamed with `myfile.txt`?

Comment: I have only ONE .txt file per folder

Comment: Try: `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir mv {} myfile.txt \;`

Comment: find: The relative path ‘\342\200\252C’ is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

Comment: With `-exec`, it will move all txt files into `$PWD/myfile.txt`, so only the last one will survive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find -exec` runs the specified command in the current directory. That means your `mv` command is moving all the files to the directory you run `find` from, not simply renaming them in-place.

You can use `find -execdir` instead, which executes commands from the directory of the matched file.

```
# Temporarily set PATH to a value that doesn't include '.' 
PATH=/bin find . -type f -name '*.txt' -execdir mv {} myfile.txt \;
```

Less efficient but potentially useful for more complex commands, you can also use `-exec` with a shell command. Note that in this example we pass the found files as arguments to the script, rather than injecting them by putting `{}` into the command string.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec /bin/bash -c 'mv "${1}" "${1%/*}/myfile.txt"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: thanks tjm, would you just explain why we should not include a '.' in the PATH ?  :)

Comment: GNU find will refuse to run an `-execdir` command if it thinks your PATH is insecure. See in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html): `If you use ‘-execdir’, you must ensure that the PATH variable contains only absolute directory names. Having an empty element in PATH or explicitly including ‘.’ (or any other non-absolute name) is insecure. GNU find will refuse to run if you use ‘-execdir’ and it thinks your PATH setting is insecure.`